# Why is not an ovious check of human input not enough for robots?

Tags: forms, validation, bots

I'm not a newbie in all areas and I searched for some answers to prohibit robots from posting forms on my web-site. I use the reCaptcha but it really IS a comlicated way to send a form. Read about a couple of tips as well but I really cannot understand why it isn't safe to refer to some graphic element on the page and require input of "how many..." etc. to validate sending the form.

So my simple question is HOW on Earth a robot would be able to identify that there, for example, is seven mushrooms in a pic on site? Would be a simple way and not by random pics etc. Naturally a human spammer would be able to send but do those really visit any obscure site searching for any kind of user input possibility to do their malicious work?

In my case I've just put out a site about our band and would like to give visitors possiblities to send e-mail as well as adding simple comments in a "flat" messageboard (controlled by PHP and SQL). Would be that much more Clean not to force them trying to read those reCaptcha pics. I agree that it's safe BUT ther's too many unreadable ones and a vivistor might gets tired and skip.

Anyway, my messageboard do NOT send any mails. It just put their single comment out on the page. I'm able to maintain and delete messages I do not want there, but should I worrie about thousands of robot messages, attempting to fill in forms to obtain mailadresses even if there are none?

Sometimes you need to ask the "stupid" questions so excuse my ignorance if this was covered somewhere. I searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: There are picture / image captcha's out there.